# Solve $16x^{-3}=-2$

Tags: problem-solving

> Solve $16x^{-3}=-2$.

My working:
\begin{align}
16x^{-3}&=-2\\
\frac{1}{16x^{3}}&=-2\\
\frac{16x^3}{16x^3}&=-32x^3\\
1&=-32x^{3}\\
-32x^{3}&=1\\
-32x&=\sqrt[3]{1}\\
-32x&=1\\
x&=\frac{-1}{32}
\end{align}

Is this right? What have I done wrong?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Note that $16x^{-3}=\frac {16}{x^3}$ and not $\frac 1{16x^3}$

Comment: @AlexR Yeah something I've been meaning to do for a while. Thanks, you have encouraged me. Perhaps it's not as hard as I first thought. The initial thought when looking at that link is a rather daunting one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing two things wrong.

1. Interpreting $16x^{-3}$ as $\frac{1}{16x^3}$, it means $\frac{16}{x^3}$.
2. Only taking the cube root of $x^3$ in $-32x^3$.

Answer (score 3):

$$16x^{-3} = -2$$

$$\frac{16}{x^3} = -2$$

$$-8 = x^3$$

$$x = -2$$

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you could check that $x=-\frac1{32}$ doesn't solve $16x^{-3} = -2$.
Instead you can solve as follows
$$\begin{align*}
16 x^{-3} & = -2  & \text{reciprocal } a=b \Leftrightarrow \frac1a = \frac1b \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac1{16} x^3 & = -\frac12 & \text{multiply by } 16\\
\Leftrightarrow x^3 & = -8 & \text{take cube root}\\
\Leftrightarrow x & = \sqrt[3]{-8} = -2
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Maxima I obtain the following:

[x=1-sqrt(3)*%i,x=sqrt(3)*%i+1,x=-2]

Where %i = sqrt(-1)